# Angular 1.4.8 - how to use ternary operator in laravel blade?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-blade

I have JSON data in following format -
**{"Front head room":"38.0 in.","height adjustable driver seat":true,"multi-level heating passenger seat":true,"sport front seats":true,"Front shoulder room":"55.6 in.","multi-level heating driver seat":true,"8 -way power driver seat":true,"leatherette":true,"Front leg room":"42.3 in.","4 -way manual passenger seat adjustment":true,"Front hip room":"50.3 in."}**

In blade template, data is showing as -

[image]

I want to use **right tick icon** in place of **true** , I have following codes in blade -

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fr1">
        @{{key}} - @{{value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying something like -

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fr1">
        @{{key}} - @{{(value == true) ? <i class="fa fa-check"> : value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

But it is not working, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use a ternary expression outside of the code inside the HTML.  But, you may use two tags for the positive and negative cases, e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in fr1">
        @{{key}} - <span style="@{{(value == true) ? 'display:none' : ''}}">@{{value}}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-check" style="@{{(value != true) ? 'display:none' : ''}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

The logic here is that if `value` be truthy, then the `<span>`, containing the text of `value`, would be hidden, and the right tick icon from `<i>` would show.  If `value` be falsy, then the `<span>` becomes visible, but then we hide the `<i>`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is showing only right tick icon for all values, it should show only if the value is true.

Comment: @SachinVairagi Please reload the page.  I have made some changes perhaps since you saw my answer.

Comment: I have tried it but not working :(  , tried with alternate way like - @{{key}} - <span style="@{{!value ? '' : 'display:none'}}">@{{value}}</span> but still not working..

Comment: OK, when you run my code, what does the actual HTML output look like?  Let's try to fix it by using the actual HTML being rendered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your idea works. I made little changes and it worked - @{{key}} - <span style="@{{(value == true) ? 'display:none' : ''}}">@{{value}}</span><i class="fa fa-check" style="@{{(value != true) ? 'display:none' : ''}}">

Comment: Please update it in your answer, it may help others :)